# How to recover Principal Database up and running from Mirror Database due to Database Down

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 principal is down (Database live server is down because of abruptly interrupted) and found that the mirror DB server is running and up. They are configured on different ip addressess (Principal - A, Mirror - B)
Right now principal live server and mirror database server states are the following:

```
Mirror - B
name        Database State      Mirroring State     Mirroring Role
live            ONLINE          SYNCHRONIZED        PRINCIPAL
live_sub            RESTORING       SYNCHRONIZED        MIRROR


Principal - A
name        Database State      Mirroring State     Mirroring Role
live            RESTORING       SYNCHRONIZED        MIRROR
```

I would like to know if principal DB server will be automatically recovered. If not, what will I need to configure? I appreciate for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The database is in synchronized state, so you can just failover manually back to the former principal.

Comment: Will I run these two scripts now or will I wait till which state of Principal server? Sorry I am new to this mirroring. Alter Database TESTDB Set Partner Resume; Alter Database TESTDB Set Partner Failover;

Comment: Just the `set partner failover` should do (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/2009/02/22/Will-the-Mirror-automatically-fail-back-to-the-original-Principal-when-it-comes-back-online/)